# How to maintain trade off between number of columns in table vs join operations?

Tags: database, data-structures

I have learnt that if there are more columns in table, then get those results using join query.

How to decide the max number of columns in table?

How feasible is "Join Operation" if too many table involved?

**And if join operation hurts performance**

Can we define all columns in one table to get rid of join operation?

I found many developer telling me that its better to have few extra columns if needed frequently in most database operation than to have multiple tables.

Comment: Are you talking of one-to-one relationships?

Comment: @thorstenmüller : Yes

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan?

Comment: @MichaelT : have not came across "Query plan". From the first look at wiki , it seems helpful in understanding concepts. Thank you .

Comment: @Ritesh Nobody can answer your question I guess. Also you might find this useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @Ritesh The query performance is far beyond the number of columns and tables -- including `join` queries, and it depends on so many external factors, from that specific engine implementation to the indexes, etc.

Comment: @Mahdi Thanks for your reference. Lets say one ResultSet can be gained using join operation of 2 or 3 tables.

And Same ResultSet can be prepared from keeping needed columns inside one single table. Then which is better way?

Comment: @Ritesh Obviously the exact same columns within a table will be faster than multiple tables, but do you really need that much of performance and micro-optimization? I suggest you first design your tables in a way that make sense, then if it was slow think about the optimization. `join`s are not bad by default and they could be extremely helpful if you use them wisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The golden rule for software design: it depends.

The trouble with trying to evaluate it the way you are doing it is that there is insufficient information.  What I have seen work well is to focus on just having a good **normalized** design (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and use appropriate indexes for performance, then de-normalize as a last resort as you find performance problems.

For example, our DBA found that after scaling our app up after a decade, a lot of the database's time was spent `JOIN`ing to additional tables just to get a single column.  Duplicating a couple of key columns into a couple tables (I think he used a trigger to maintain it, but not sure, wasn't my area) to eliminate a few frequently used `JOIN`s helped improve performance.  It wasn't a huge deal, but imagine if 90% of your queries got 10% faster.  That could be worth it.

Again, this was after 10 years of observing and optimizing.  Don't jump in to this sort of optimization.  Just focus on normalization until you find a compelling reason to de-normalize.

This trade-off you are looking for is way too case-by-case.  There is no specific maximum # of columns that I can tell you is too many.

Comment: Thank you Brandon. That's very clear. The question was also clear enough to expect answer. I think top members should be little gentle to newbie.